# Parallax double background mouse move image effect

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, parallax.js

Thanks for read this post.

I have a website with this section:

With this code:[Actual Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4vBG.png)

I need to give to the rocket image a little move when the user move the mouse, I have try to reach this goal with this changes:

When i change this codes i get:

[Issue Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uR3E.png)

CSS:

**Original**:

```
  .calltoaction {padding:55px 0 360px; 
  background-image: url(../img/other/calltoaction.png), url(../img/other/b.png) ;
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom center, bottom center;
  background-size:cover, cover;
  overflow:hidden;
  }
```

**Change**:

```
  .calltoaction {padding:55px 0 360px; 
  background-image:  url(../img/other/b.png) ;
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom center, bottom center;
  background-size:cover, cover;
  overflow:hidden;
  z-index: 1;

  }
  .calltoactionb {
  z-index: 4;
padding:55px 0 360px;
  background-image: url(../img/other/calltoaction.png) ;
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom center, bottom center;
  background-size:cover, cover;
  overflow:hidden;
  }
```

**HTML**:

**Original**:

```
  <div class="calltoaction wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="200ms">
      <div class="row"> <div class="col-sm-12" id="mousemoveoneindex">
          <h2 class="text-center white-text-fixed-home">Cloud Servers <strong>70</strong>% más rápidos<span class="red-color-rocket">Construimos Soluciones en <strong>Segundos</strong></span></h2>
          <div class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-success" href="https://aponte-systems.com/secure/Registro/Cloud-Panel">Regístrate en CloudPanel</a></div>
        </div> </div>  </div>


        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/parallax/3.1.0/parallax.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var scene = document.getElementById('scene_index_a');
        var parallaxInstance = new Parallax(scene, {
          relativeInput: true
        });
        var scene2 = document.getElementById('scene_index_b');
        var parallaxInstance2 = new Parallax(scene2, {
          relativeInput: true
        });
        var scene3 = document.getElementById('scene_index_c');
        var parallaxInstance3 = new Parallax(scene3, {
          relativeInput: true
        });

        </script>
```

**Change**:

```
  <div class="calltoaction wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="200ms">  
      <div class="row"> <div class="col-sm-12" id="mousemoveoneindex">
          <h2 class="text-center white-text-fixed-home">Cloud Servers <strong>70</strong>% más rápidos<span class="red-color-rocket">Construimos Soluciones en <strong>Segundos</strong></span></h2>
          <div class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-success" href="https://aponte-systems.com/secure/Registro/Cloud-Panel">Regístrate en CloudPanel</a></div>
        </div> </div>  <div data-hover-only="yes" data-scalar-x="10" data-scalar-y="10" id="scene_index_d"><div class="calltoactionb" data-depth="0.6" > </div>  </div> </div>


        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/parallax/3.1.0/parallax.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var scene = document.getElementById('scene_index_a');
        var parallaxInstance = new Parallax(scene, {
          relativeInput: true
        });
        var scene2 = document.getElementById('scene_index_b');
        var parallaxInstance2 = new Parallax(scene2, {
          relativeInput: true
        });
        var scene3 = document.getElementById('scene_index_c');
        var parallaxInstance3 = new Parallax(scene3, {
          relativeInput: true
        });
        var scene4 = document.getElementById('scene_index_d');
        var parallaxInstance4 = new Parallax(scene4, {
          relativeInput: true
        });

        </script>
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with parallax.js, but part of your issue may be that you have two CSS values for each of your background images' different properties (left over from the original where there were two background images, I assume) instead of just one value for each property. Also your JS has four parallax scenes, but I only see `#scene_index_d` in the HTML.

Comment: Thanks, yes i have see this bug and correct but i continue with the same issue.